# i need this continue to skip the entire while loop but it skips just the if loop (i think)

Tags: loops, if-statement, while-loop, try-catch, continue

```
while continue_bool:

     try:
            name = input("Name (str): ")
            if (name in used_names):
                print("This name is already in use")
                continue
            quantity = int(input("quantity (int): "))
```

here is the code. i tested the continue statement and it does what i want it to do in a simple for loop. it seems here the if (x in y) creates a loop of its own that the continue just restarts. how do i make the continue restart the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the continue keyword outside the if block

Comment: i need it to only activate if the if statement is true though...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).